# How do I gain access to the on-chain funds with hsm_secret?

Tags: lightning-network, wallet-recovery

I had a Core Lightning node running properly, but it suddenly somehow stopped working. I force-closed the only channel I owned (from my other node), and since I can't start the lightning daemon (with `lightningd`) of the problematic node, I can only access the funds with the
`hsm_secret`.

How is this going to work? I did setup another node, replaced its `hsm_secret`, ran the `listfunds` command and got nothing:

```
bitcoin@raspibolt:~/.lightningmobile2/bitcoin $ lightning-cli --lightning-dir=/home/bitcoin/.lightningmobile2 --conf=/home/bitcoin/.lightningmobile2/lightningd.conf listfunds
{
   "outputs": [],
   "channels": []
}
```

So, after I re-synced, I ran `listfunds` and it returned me the same, exact message (no outputs). I had some hope that I'd recover my force-closed funds that way, but bad luck.

I just want to say that I still have the problematic sqlite3 file, if that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c-lightning node backup-restore](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92801/c-lightning-node-backup-restore)

Comment: Hello. After a lot of time syncing, it doesn't work. I'm using the same hsm_secret, and once I enter ``listfunds`` I get no outputs.

Comment: Hi Angelo, please edit your question to incorporate what happened after trying what Michael proposed into the question post.

Comment: Hello @Murch, I have edited my post.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: Hey @bl0ck3d, read this: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5158920.msg60919627#msg60919627

Comment: thank you @Angelo, but how can I know the p2wpkh and node_id, if I only have the hsm_secret?

Comment: @bl0ck3d, you can't. hsm_secret is the respective to a seed phrase. No more information is disclosed by the hsm_secret.

Comment: @Angelo, so if I have no backup of whatever p2wpkh address it is, I can't recover the funds?

Comment: I guess no.....